Why can't you prove by induction that $\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n \right)^C = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n^C$?
In the solutions to Exercise 1.2.12 of his Understanding Analysis, Abbott states that it is not possible to prove using induction that $$\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n \right)^C = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n^C.$$
However, induction can of course be used to prove that $$(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n)^C = A_1^C \cap A_2^C \cap \dots \cap A_n^C,$$ for any finite value of $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I don't understand why this result cannot be generalised to accommodate an infinite number of sets.

Induction only works to prove statements for every natural number $n$. It cannot be applied for cases regarding 'a countably infinite number of objects' such as this one.

That is because $\infty$ is not a natural number - it is not a number at all, right?

Well, it's basically the statement of the induction method. It proves propositions for every natural number, that's it.

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding how induction works, but maybe this illustrates what I meant: consider the fact that, if $A$ is a set with $n$ elements, then $\lvert \mathcal{P}(A) \rvert = 2^n$. This can be proved by induction, and thus it is true for every natural $n$. This means you can prove that the cardinality of the power set of a singleton is $2^1 = 2$, the cardinality of the power set of a set with two elements is $2^2 = 4$, and so forth. 1/2

But it doesn't make any sense to try and prove that the cardinality of the power set of a set with infinitely many elements is $2^{\infty}$ because this is not well-defined. Is this similar to the case in my question? 2/2

That's not an ideal example because we define $2^\kappa$ for transfinite cardinals in analogy with the finite case as the cardinality of the powerset of a size-$\kappa$ set. Here's a better example: you can prove by induction each natural $n$ is finite, but...

But still, isn't that because $\infty$ is not a natural number at all? Or am I confused on how mathematicians define and work with infinities? If $\infty$ were a natural number, then induction would apply (no?).

@RiccardoIorio Infinity is not a natural number, full stop.

So this is why you can't prove the statement in my question using induction, right?

A similar case is to prove $1-\frac13+\frac15-\dots$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Infinite_series) is always rational using induction, but $\frac\pi4$ isn't.

As many commenters already stated, induction only proves the statement for finite numbers, and cannot on its own be used to prove statements that go beyong finite cases. As a classic example of where induction would fail, consider collections of open intervals $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ (we cound the empty set as an open interval as well). It is not hard to prove that the intersection of any finite collection of these intervals is also an open interval, but $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n}) = [a,b]$ isn't. So here, induction would fail.
There is a more powerful version of induction that can be applied to infinite cases called transfinite induction. The most thorough examination of it you will probably find in an axiomatic set theory textbook, but here's a short explanation: Basically, we can extend the natural numbers to a class of "numbers" called the ordinals. We encode each natural number as sets by inductively defining each natural number to be the set containing all previous natural numbers. So $0$ would be the empty set, $1$ would be the set containing $0$, $10$ would be $\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ and so on. This may seem strange at first, but it allows us to define ordinals in the following "inductive" manner:
First, the empty set is an ordinal. Second, for any ordinal $\alpha$ we can define the "next" ordinal to be $\alpha + 1 := \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$. Finally, any set of ordinals $A$ closed under membership (that is, $\alpha \in \beta \in A$ means $\alpha \in A$) is an ordinal (note that in ordinals, we define the relation $\alpha < \beta$ as equivalent to $\alpha \in \beta$). This makes the set of all natural numbers, which is usually denoted as $\omega$, an ordinal. In fact, it is a special type of ordinal called a limit ordinal, which just means it is not directly above a smaller ordinal.
So, here's how transfinite induction works: The first two steps are identical, you prove that a statement is true for $0$, and that if it's true for some ordinal $\alpha$, it's true for $\alpha + 1$. However, there's the added 3rd step where you have to prove that, for some limit ordinal $\alpha$, if the statement is true for all ordinals below it, then it must be true for $\alpha$ too. If you manage to prove all 3 of these statements, your statement is true for all ordinals; which is the most powerful form of induction possible. I'm not sure if your statement could be proved using it, but it'd likely be overkill considering basic logical reasoning about elements works already.

Thank you for the detailed explanation!
